# How to annotate function, that accepts typeof class (ctor function) as parameter?

Tags: typescript, annotations

I have few classes and I want to create function, that would accepts the classes (the definitions, not the instances).

```
class Page1 {
}
class Page2 {
}

register(Page1);
register(Page2);

function Register(pageType){..}
```

how to annonate pageType parameter, so `register(new Page1());` will fail?

basically, I want eqivalent of this C# method:

```
void Register(Type pageType){..}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on [an IoC container for TypeScript](http://inversify.io/) for some time and the best way I found to do this was using generics:

```
class Page1 {
}

class Page2 {
}

interface Newable<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

function register<T>(pageType: Newable<T>){}

register<Page1>(Page1); // OK
register<Page2>(Page2); // OK

register<Page1>(new Page1()); // Error
register<Page2>(new Page2()); // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a interface 'Type' extending Function and use that in your register method,

```
interface Type extends Function { }

function Register(pageType : Type ){..}
```

And then use it like you desire,

```
class Page1 {
}
class Page2 {
}

register(Page1);
register(Page2);
```